How can I multiply all numbers by a value if numeric in a dataframe
I am using the following code (dplyr) to try multiply all numbers by a value skipping character obviously
ENID_transposed_df <- ENID_transposed_df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(.x, .x * 0.01))

This will not work. Eventually the 0.01 will become a parameter. Can someone see what I am doing incorrect?
No change to values occurred using above code

Thank you very much for all the responses. Issue resolved

Use across() to multiply all variables where(is.numeric) by 0.01:
(Scoped verbs like mutate_if have been superseded by mutate with across.)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = 1:10,
  b = 2:11,
  c = rep("z", 10)
)

df |> mutate(across(where(is.numeric), \(x) x * 0.01))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>        a     b c    
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1  0.01  0.02 z    
#>  2  0.02  0.03 z    
#>  3  0.03  0.04 z    
#>  4  0.04  0.05 z    
#>  5  0.05  0.06 z    
#>  6  0.06  0.07 z    
#>  7  0.07  0.08 z    
#>  8  0.08  0.09 z    
#>  9  0.09  0.1  z    
#> 10  0.1   0.11 z

Created on 2024-04-05 with reprex v2.1.0

Using lapply
> df |> lapply(\(.) if (is.numeric(.)) .*.01 else .) |> as.data.frame()
      a    b c
1  0.01 0.02 z
2  0.02 0.03 z
3  0.03 0.04 z
4  0.04 0.05 z
5  0.05 0.06 z
6  0.06 0.07 z
7  0.07 0.08 z
8  0.08 0.09 z
9  0.09 0.10 z
10 0.10 0.11 z


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(a = 1:10, b = 2:11, c = c("z", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


1) mutate_if Usually across is used these days in dplyr rather than mutate_if but to answer the question directly which was how to use mutate_if try any of these where df is the input dat frame:
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, `*`, 0.01)
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ .x * 0.01)

2) modifyList/nv Another way, not using dplyr, is the following.  nv from collapse gives a data frame with just the numeric columns and modifyList from base R replaces columns in the first argument with columns of the same name in the second argument.
library(collapse)

modifyList(df, nv(df) * 0.01)

3) nv<- This would also work using collapse
df01 <- df
nv(df01) <- 0.01 * nv(df01)

3a) or
`nv<-`(df, 0.01 * nv(df))

